# Export products in Perfion PIM

Tags: product, pim

I'm using Perfion PIM to manage products. But I can not find the way to export all products to csv file
Anyone using it? Please help me!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use * in the search.  Expand your row view to the number greater than the amount of skus in the database.

Comment: question asked 9 months ago. Before giving answer please take care of this as well